# How to prevent MYSQL Group by errors if no rows are returned?

Tags: mysql

I have a simple query

```
SELECT id, sum(credits_in) AS total_credits, count(id) as total_rows 
            FROM transactions  WHERE id = '$id'  GROUP BY $id
```

It works perfectly fine if there are rows (transactions by the target user), but on some queries where the target is a new user and has no transactions yet (no rows), this error comes up.

```
  Error: Can't group on 'sum(credits_in)'"
```

For now, I have a work around where i have an initial query to simply check and count the rows, before running the main query w/ sum() groupings... But I'm interested in a way where I wouldn't need to issue a row-count SQL line. I wish the main SQL would just return sum=zero if no rows were found instead of raising an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already know the ID, and there is only one involved, remove ID from the select clause and remove the group by clause. Then supply at least one row in a union to avoid the no row problem.

```
SELECT
       sum(credits_in) AS total_credits
     , count(*)-1 as total_rows 
FROM (
      SELECT 0.00 as credits _in
  union all
      SELECT credits_in
      FROM transactions
      WHERE id = '$id'
      ) as d
```